# add jbutton to jpanel after creation

Tags: java, swing, button

I'm trying to add a JButton to a JPanel sitting in a JFrame during the running of the program. The button actually works (is clickable) but doesn't appear.

```
JButton takeOffButton = new JButton();
    takeOffButton.setText("Take Off");
    takeOffButton.setBounds(30, 30, 100, 100);
    takeOffButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            Game.switchState(GameState.SPACE, Game.player.curPlanet);
        }

    });
    takeOffButton.setVisible(true);

    panel.add(takeOffButton);
```

I've set both the Frame and panel's layout to null using setLayout(null)

What might be going on here?

EDIT: I tried simply adding a jbutton to a jpanel in the panel's constructor and not even that is working..

Comment: Hi, would you mind posting a minimal and reproducible example ?

Comment: Note that it is usually a bad idea to use null layouts, since you will have great headaches if you ever run the program on a platform with a different size display, or one with a different default font, or if you want to change fonts. Learn to use layout managers!

Comment: 1) Swing components, except top level containers like JFrame, and JDialog, are visible by default 2) Swing doesn't know you added the component to the visible GUI so you need to invoke repaint(). 3) Also agree that you should be using layout managers (for too many reasons to list here), not a null layout. Learn to use Swing the way is was designed to be used.

Comment: @camickr repaint() is called many times as it is a game. Even without using the null layout and not bothering with setVisible(true), it behaves exactly like I described.

Comment: As you were asked in the first comment, please post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. The code should compile and execute, but we don't care about your game logic, only the code that attempts to add the button dynamically.

Answer (score -1):

See my comment about layout managers!
If you have a null manager, you have to override your panel's paintChildren method and place the children yourself. It is much, much simpler to use a layout manager.

Comment: (1-) no you don't have to override the paintChildren() method when using a null layout. Although, I agree you should NOT be using a null layout.